# <BR> Removal Behavior when typing a character

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

(Chrome latest version as of this date)

**Info Update**: Span is inside a contenteditable div

Is it safe to assume that (for Chrome) that `<br>` (Caret's start at the span) will be removed when the user inputs a non white space character?

For Chrome

```
<span><br/></span>
```

typing the word stack, it will turn into this, thus removing the `<br>` automatically.

```
<span>stack</span>
```

On IE11 (haven't tried <= IE10 ), using again the word stack, it produces...

```
<span>stack<br></br></span>
```

In some cases, or depending on the caret's start on user's manipulation, or the use of `Range` and `Selection`. It can also turn into this,

```
<span>stack<br>stack</br></span>
```

On FireFox, it produces,

```
 <span>stack<br></span>
```

It seems like Chrome clears `<br>` unlike IE and FF.

Furthermore, even if I target the `<br>` using range.setStart Chrome & Firefox will not render it like this

```
<span><br>HEY</br></span>
```

Chrome always like this

```
<span>hey</span>
```

and firefox would stack the text nodes over the br

Am I missing something?
In addition, is there any underlying rules regarding br deletion that I could read on? thanks.

Comment: Are you using contenteditable? If so, this is a long standing debate over all browsers. Watch this conference where they go in detail about this issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feUYwoLhE_4. I strongly recommend using Draft-js from facebook

Comment: @ViníciusNegrão yes, I'm using contenteditable. I'll look into that thanks.